# lighttpd redirect certain links to certain urls

Tags: linux, redirect, lighttpd, regex

Could someone tell me how / why is this redirect not working?

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ ".*\\.mydomain\\.com" { 
    url.redirect = ( 
        "/index\.php\?pg=mysql" => "http://mydomain.com/lean-webhosting/mysql-clustering/",
        "/index\.php\?pg=cloud_uitleg" => "http://mydomain.com/lean-webhosting/cloud-uitleg/" 
    )    
}
```

Someone any idea?  THanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ ".*\.muntinternet\.nl" { 
    url.redirect = ( 
        "/\?pg=mysql" => "http://muntinternet.nl/lean-webhosting/mysql-clustering/",
        "/\?pg=cloud_uitleg" => "http://muntinternet.nl/lean-webhosting/cloud-uitleg/" 
    )    
}
```

I needed to exclude `/index\.php`

Thanks!

Comment: Do not forget to accept your answer then. Btw, in the future, add more information in your question instead of just the configuration lines that doesn't work. It would have been interesting here to see which **real** url you want to redirect to where.

Comment: hi j0k. I just added real links to illustrate the situation. Thanks for letting me know to accept the answer as solved. It won't let me untill tomorrow.

Comment: Well, I do not want to see real path to your website :) You still can use `example.com`. But, here we need a real example of url you want to redirect. For example, `http://example.com/?pg=mysql` So it will be easy to see that your redirect won't work if the rule start with `index.php`, you see?

Comment: There is no http://muntinternet.nl/?pg=mysql. There is http://muntinternet.nl/index.php?pg=mysql  however non of these should be used if redirecting these two specific urls. THe same example as you can see above is used within lighttpd.conf.

Comment: I think you should remove the first `/` from `"/\?pg=mysql"` (and the other line too) then, both http://muntinternet.nl/index.php?pg=mysql & http://muntinternet.nl/?pg=mysql will be redirected

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to replace `".*\\.mydomain\\.com"` with `".*\.mydomain\.com"` and restart `lighttpd`. If that doesn't help: please explain *how* the redirect isn't working for you.

Comment: Thaks for the regexp Asgar. That was indeed one of the problems. I've excluded the index.php part and it worked.